# Remove � Special Character from String

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying to remove junk character from a stream of html strings using PHP but haven't been successfull yet.  Is there any special syntax or logics to remove special character from the string?

I had tried this so far, but ain't working

```
 $new_string = preg_replace("�", "", $HtmlText); 
 echo '<pre>'.$new_string.'</pre>';
```

Comment: if you see '�' it means you're using the wrong character encoding. It is used by PHP to represent anything it cannot render. So, it can be anything.

Comment: When you get �'s there is always something wrong. Either by character encoding, page charset, database charset and the like.- Removing �'s is symptom treatment, but it does not cure the disease.

Comment: As David said, you're database encoding is incorrect for content being stored. I'm guess you need some utf encoding and it's probably using a plain character set currently. Like stated, replacing/stripping will 'remove them but is a very poor answer :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to mismatch in Charset between database and front-end.  Correcting this will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
\p{S}
```

You can use this.`\p{S} matches math symbols, currency signs, dingbats, box-drawing characters, etc`

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rK5lU1/30

```
$re = "/\\p{S}/i";
$str = "asdas�sadsad";
$subst = "";

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Answer (score -3):

function clean($string) {

```
      return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
```

}